# Sinatra cannot generate schema or show migration status

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rake

My Sinatra apps no longer seem to do anything when running `rake db:migrate` or `rake db:migrate:status`.  No error messages or any other output, and the schema is not generated.  `rake db:create_migration` works as expected.  Old apps that previously worked no longer do.  Rails apps still work fine.

I have had a number of Ruby/RVM/rbenv issues but I think (hope?) they are settled, and am using Ruby 2.6.0, Sinatra 2.0.7, Active Record 6.0.0 & Sinatra-activerecord 2.0.14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are issues with ActiveRecord 6.0.  Changing my Gemfile to 
`activerecord, "5.2.3"` fixed everything.